# How to conditionally group data based on values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I have the following ordered data frame which has position of specific lines in a text file

data:

```
index position 
  0     125
  1     256
  2     314
  3     355
  4     549
  5     601
  6     654
  7     727
  8     1100
  9     1217
```

I have another dataframe which has messages msg1 , msg2 and msg3 along with their position in the text file and can have several instances. These messages signify how to group the data

message:

```
index position  message 
  0     210     msg1
  1     313     msg2
  2     525     msg3
  3     575     msg2
  4     632     msg1
  5     731     msg3
```

Conditions

a) if the line is before first encountered message ( not necessarily msg1 , identified by position) then line will be classified as grade A

b) if the line is after last message( not necessarily msg3 ,identified by position) then line will be classified as :

```
a) if msg1 is last: grade A1

b) if msg2 is last: grade A2

c) if msg3 is last: grade A3
```

c) if the line is between two messages i.e start of msg[i] and end of msg[j] then line will be classified as 'grade A' + str(i)

I have tried the if else statements and failed to implement it correctly. Any easier way to do it without any hardcoding of positions in message frame will be appreciated.

Expected output is a pandas series/dataframe or a list with lines grouped as per the condition

```
index position  group
  0     125    grade A
  1     256    grade A1
  2     314    grade A2
  3     355    grade A2
  4     549    grade A3
  5     601    grade A2
  6     654    grade A1
  7     727    grade A1
  8     1100   grade A3
  9     1217   grade A3
```

Comment: what is your expected\ output ?

Comment: i have updated the question and the expected output is shown there

Answer (score 0):

For each row in the messages dataframe, we add the position of the next message, for easy comparison:

```
messages = messages.join(messages['position'].shift(-1).rename('next_position'))
```

Add the message for each row in the data:

```
data['class'] = 0
for index, row in messages.iterrows():
  data.loc[data['position'].between(row['position'],row['next_position']),'class'] = row['message']
```

Add the 'edge' cases:

```
data.loc[data['position'].between(0,messages['position'].min()),'class'] = 'msg'
data.loc[data['position'].between(messages['position'].max(),np.inf),'class'] = messages.iloc[-1]['message']
```

And replace the messages with your class

```
for message_code in data['class'].unique():
    data.replace(message_code,'A'+message_code.split('msg')[-1],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would:

- concat both dataframe
- add a new column `grade` for all rows having a message computed as `'grade A'` + number of the message
- sort the concatenated dataframe on the `position` column
- use `fillna` to fill the grade column with the grade of previous message
- use again `fillna` to set any row before the first message to `'grade A'`
- extract the rows having no message to build the result dataframe

Code could be:

```
tmp = pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False).sort_values(
    ['position'])

tmp.loc[~tmp['message'].isna(),'grade'] = 'grade A' + tmp.loc[
    ~tmp['message'].isna(),'message'].str[3]

tmp['grade']=tmp['grade'].fillna(method='ffill').fillna('grade A')

resul = tmp.loc[tmp.message.isna()].drop(columns=['message'])
```

With your sample data, it gives as expected:

```
index  position     grade
    0       125   grade A
    1       256  grade A1
    2       314  grade A2
    3       355  grade A2
    4       549  grade A3
    5       601  grade A2
    6       654  grade A1
    7       727  grade A1
    8      1100  grade A3
    9      1217  grade A3
```

Comment: Using `.fillna` is most definitely better than iterating on rows (as in my answer). I'd accept this one.

Comment: for some reason the pd.concat creates another column 0 for me and I have three columns instead of two